# Brackets in HQL not ntranslated to SQL

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is my HQL:

```
Query query = createQueryOnCurrentSession("DELETE Email e " +
                "where " +
                "(status = :sent and creationTime <= :creation)" +
                "or " +
                "(status = :error and maxEttempts >= :maxEttempts)");
```

Here is the generated SQL:

```
delete from `email` where `status`=? and `creation_time`<=? or `status`=? and `attempts`>=?
```

Question: why are the brackets not in the SQL?
I would expect it to be:

```
delete from `email` where (`status`=? and `creation_time`<=?) or (`status`=? and `attempts`>=?)
```

may be as alternative I will delete in 2 requests?

```
delete from `email` where `status`=? and `creation_time`<=?
delete from `email` where `status`=? and `attempts`>=?
```

Comment: try escaping the parentheses like so: `\(`

Comment: single `"\("` doesn't compile (of course) and double `"\\("` throw exception: `org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '\' [DELETE com.grroo.model.Email e where \(status = :sent and creationTime <= :creation\)or \(status = :error and attempts >= :maxAttempts\)]`

Comment: I think you can append query string as your condition then execute

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's actually a feature.

Since `and` has precedence over `or`, hibernate knows it, and removes brackets.

You don't need those brackets there.

Comment: I know it is like that in some databases... but is it a standard for all DB I will ever use? Can you reference please? I could not find it...

Comment: I am not sure if it is a fixed standard, but must DBs use it like that.

Comment: This exactly what troubles me. Maybe there is way to tell hibernate to leave the brackets?

Comment: If there is a database that treats things differently, then the Hibernate dialect for that database can accomodate it.

Answer (score 2):

**Logical operator AND has higher order of precedence than logical operator OR**

for Operator precedence, follow the link

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx

http://docs.oracle.com/html/A85397_01/operator.htm#997691
```

Comment: Here are only biggest 3 DB providers, which ofcourse use that standard.